# PopcornJS Youtube Player and Flask/Python

Tags: python, video-streaming, html5-video, youtube-javascript-api, popcornjs

I'm trying to build a simple web application using PopcornJS in Python. I want to simply mute the volume of a youtube video and autoplay it but it seems to not be working/ there may be a bug in PopcornJS's youtube video player.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    var popcorn = Popcorn.youtube( "#video" , 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/XMW2lbNVaXY');
    popcorn.volume(0);
    popcorn.autoplay(true);
</script>
```

and the html

```
<div id="video"></div>
```

Seems like the volume control and the autoplay are not working. If I switch to a non youtube video everything works fine. Also if I look at my console during run time I see the following error

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing 
a frame with origin "http://127.0.0.1:5000". Protocols, domains, 
and ports must match.
```

Googling the problem revealed that it might be a chrome bug, but I'm not sure. Anyone know what's wrong? Thanks!